# How to update & transition ordinalScale axis in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, es6-class

I thought I'd learn a little about ES6 classes while doing some d3 work, and so I made an ordinal bar chart class ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1z26gwcj/2/)). It displays multiple series of data (eg:

```
[
    [{"label":"apple", "value" :25},
    {"label":"orange", "value": 16},
    {"label":"pear", "value":19}],

    [{"label":"banana", "value" :12},
    {"label":"grape", "value": 6},
    {"label":"peach", "value":5}]
];
```

I'm trying to get the update part working (where you provide new data and the bars/axis transition nicely). Unfortunately much of the example code is for v3, which doesn't seem to work with v4 like I'm using. The specific method is:

```
updateData(data){
    //get an array of the ordinal labels out of the data
    let labels = function(data){
        let result = [];
        for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            for (let j=0; j<data[i].length; j++){
                result.push(data[i][j].label);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }(data);

    //loop through the (potentially multiple) series in the data array
    for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        let series = data[i],
            bars = this.svg.selectAll(".series" + i)
        bars
            .data(series)
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", ("series" + i))
            .classed("bar", true)
          .merge(bars) 
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("height", this.y.bandwidth())
            .attr("y", (d) => { return this.y(d.label); })
            .transition().duration(500) //grow bars horizontally on load
            .attr("width", (d) => { return this.x(d.value); });
        bars.exit().remove();
    }

    //update domain with new labels
    this.y.domain(labels);
    //change the y axis
    this.svg.select(".yaxis")
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(this.yAxis)
}
```

I'm trying to base the update pattern on [Mike Bostock's code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

I'm getting an internal d3 error from the `.call(this.yAxis)`, the transition doesn't animate, and the yaxis doesn't update. Additionally, the bars don't transition either. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

- Update a scaleOrdinal/scaleBand axis BEFORE updating data join, otherwise the bars won't be able to find their y scale attribute `(y(d.yourOrdinalLabel)`. The axis code hence needs to go before the bars code.
- `bars` (or whatever element you join to the data) should be declared as the result of that join operation, so that it can be chained with `.attr()` for the visual attributes. `let bars = svg.selectAll(".yourClass").data(yourData);`
- It's more sensible to have a simple `update` method in the class if you're only going to be toggling exclusion of existing data series, not adding new data. See updated fiddle.

[Working jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1z26gwcj/3/)